# How to get elevateZoom to work with multiple images

Tags: javascript, shopify

I can only get elevateZoom to work with one image.
So when I click on a thumbnail that updates the image to the selected one the zoom no longer works.

Code:

```
<div class="product-single__photo--flex-wrapper">
<div class="product-single__photo--flex">
    {% include 'image-style' with image: featured_image, width: 575, height: 850, small_style: true, wrapper_id: wrapper_id, img_id_class: img_id_class %}
    <div id="{{ wrapper_id }}" class="product-single__photo--container product-single__photo--container-thumb">
        <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper" style="padding-top:{{ 1 | divided_by: featured_image.aspect_ratio | times: 100}}%;">
            {% assign img_url = featured_image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' %}
            <img id="zoom_03" class="product-single__photo lazyload {{ img_id_class }}"
              src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '300x300' }}"
                                       data-zoom-image="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1080x1080' }}"
              data-src="{{ img_url }}"
              data-widths="[180, 360, 590, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
              data-aspectratio="{{ featured_image.aspect_ratio }}"
              data-sizes="auto"
              {% if section.settings.zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %}
              data-image-id="{{ featured_image.id }}"
              alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}"
                 data-zoom="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024', scale: 2 }}">

            <noscript>
                <img id="zoom_03" class="product-single__photo"
                src="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'master' }}"
                data-zoom-image="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1080x1080' }}"
                {% if section.settings.zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %}
                alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" data-image-id="{{ featured_image.id }}" data-zoom="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024', scale: 2 }}">
            </noscript>
            <script>
                $('#zoom_03').ezPlus({
                    zoomType: 'inner',
                    cursor: 'crosshair'
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

This is being used on Shopify. One image works, multiple don't.
Any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Example here - https://allsops.myshopify.com/products/zoom-test

Comment: Don't use an `id` but a `class` instead. And repeating an `id` name is not a valid HTML and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Thank you this solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Drip's comment above.

**The way to fix this was to change it from id to class.**

I was following the guide on the elevateZoom-Plus website, which wasn't correct for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update main image attribute also with thumbnail image attributes

Comment: How do I go about doing that?